# Angular2: render component without its wrapping tag

Tags: javascript, angular

I am struggling to find a way to do this. In a parent component, the template describes a `table` and its `thead` element, but delegates rendering the `tbody` to another component, like this:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody *ngFor="let entry of getEntries()">
    <my-result [entry]="entry"></my-result>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Each myResult component renders its own `tr` tag, basically like so:

```
<tr>
  <td>{{ entry.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ entry.time }}</td>
</tr>
```

The reason I'm not putting this directly in the parent component (avoiding the need for a myResult component) is that the myResult component is actually more complicated than shown here, so I want to put its behaviour in a separate component and file.

The resulting DOM looks bad. I believe this is because it is invalid, as `tbody` can only contain `tr` elements [(see MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/tbody), but my generated (simplified) DOM is :

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <my-result>
      <tr>
        <td>Bob</td>
        <td>128</td>
      </tr>
    </my-result>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <my-result>
      <tr>
        <td>Lisa</td>
        <td>333</td>
      </tr>
    </my-result>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there any way we can get the same thing rendered using a child component to encapsulate the rendering of the table row without the wrapping `<my-result>` tag?

I have looked at `ng-content`, `DynamicComponentLoader`, the `ViewContainerRef`, but they don't seem to provide a solution to this as far as I can see.

Comment: can you please show a working example ?

Comment: The right answer is there, with a plunker sample https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671235/remove-host-component-tag-from-html-in-angular-4

Comment: None of the proposed answer are working, or are complete.
The right answer is described here with a plunker sample https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671235/remove-host-component-tag-from-html-in-angular-4

Answer (score 168, accepted):

You can use attribute selectors

```
@Component({
  selector: '[myTd]'
  ...
})
```

and then use it like

```
<td myTd></td>
```

Comment: Does the selector of your component contain the `[]`? Did you add the component to `declarations: [...]` of a module? If the component is registered in a different module, did you add this other module to `imports: [...]` of the module where you want to use the component?

Comment: Actually I am getting a different error, sorry for deleting my previous comment it was irrelevant. My error is this: `ERROR TypeError: el.setAttribute is not a function`

Comment: My usage is as follows `<ng-container smMenu class="nav navbar-nav" [submenus]="root?.Submenus" [title]="root?.Title"></ng-container>`

Comment: I assume `el.setAttribute` is custom code of yours. Perhaps a `this.` is missing, or something else is wrong in this code.

Comment: No `setAttribute` is not my code. But I've figured it out, I needed to use the actual top level tag in my template as the tag for my component instead of `ng-container` so new working usage is `<ul smMenu class="nav navbar-nav" [submenus]="root?.Submenus" [title]="root?.Title"></ul>`

Comment: You can't set attribute component on ng-container because it is removed from the DOM. That's why you need to set it on an actual HTML tag.

Comment: @AviadP. Thanks much... I knew there was a minor change that was required and I was losing my mind over this. So instead of this:
`<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li-navigation [navItems]="menuItems"></li-navigation>
 </ul>`
I used this (after changing li-navigation to an attribute selector)
`<ul class="nav navbar-nav" li-navigation [navItems]="menuItems"></ul>`

Comment: @BharatDBhadresha I don't understand what your edit suggestion is for.

Comment: I tried to use this method with <ng-container  myTd></ng-container> but it didn't work -Error on setAttribute for ng-container element-, i want the component to decide which item to print not use td as mentioned, anyone can help?

Comment: this answer doesn't work if you're trying to augment a material compoent e.g.
<mat-toolbar my-toolbar-rows>
will complain that you can only have one component selector not multiple.
I could go <my-toolbar-component>
but then it's putting the mat-toolbar inside a div

Comment: In case you need to pass an object to embedded component. <tr app-team *ngFor="let team of uniqueTeams" [team]="team"></tr>

Comment: This doesn't work. dunno why it's everywhere as a solution. 
"The selector should be used as an element (https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-05-03) (component-selector)tslint(1)"

Comment: This solution works for simple cases (like OP's), but if you need to create a `my-results` that inside can spawn more `my-results`, then you need [`ViewContainerRef`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewContainerRef) (check [@Slim's answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56887630/979505)). The reason this solution doesn't work in that case is that the first attribute selector goes in a `tbody`, but where would the internal selector be? It can't be in a `tr` and you can't put a `tbody` inside of another `tbody`.

Comment: That's great but I want *no* tag, instead of a div/td/whatever with myTd attribute

Comment: @gyozokudor I believe you, but I didn't develop Angular. So all I could do is to provide an answer that comes as close as possible while being limited by what Angular provides and by my limited knowledge of the world.

Comment: Also, the angular community kinda didn't like this approach https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#style-05-03

Comment: @karina I agree that you shouldn't do this without a specific requirement like the one in the original question.

Comment: I don't know why this has so many upvotes? `<td myTd></td>` injects the component, which in turn makes it  `<td myTd><my-result>
      <tr>
        <td>Lisa</td>
        <td>333</td>
      </tr>
    </my-result></td>`. Which doesn't get rid of the nesting.

Comment: @alex351becaus it's probably still the best you can get. So when no perfect solution exists, should then no answer being posted instead of what's the best we got so far?

Comment: Just to be clear, your answers helped me a lot of times and I appreciate your effort more than most of the others here. But https://stackoverflow.com/a/56887630/3934886 answer comes much closer to the request. table > th > td can't handle angular tags inside well.

Comment: @alex351 thank you for the kind words. No worries, everything that helps visitors solve their problems is highly welcome! My answer reflects my knowledge at the time. Sadly, I don't have the time and energy anymore to keep my answers updated.

Answer (score 81):

You need "ViewContainerRef" and inside my-result component do something like this:

`.html`:

```
<ng-template #template>
    <tr>
       <td>Lisa</td>
       <td>333</td>
    </tr>
</ng-template>
```

`.ts`:

```
@ViewChild('template', { static: true }) template;


constructor(
  private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef
) { }

ngOnInit() {
  this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you. I used in Angular 8 the following instead: `@ViewChild('template', {static: true}) template;`

Comment: This worked. I had a situation i was using css display:grid and you can't have it still have the <my-result> tag as first element in the parent with all of the child elements of my-result rending as siblings to my-result. The problem was that one extra ghost element still broke the grids 7 columns "grid-template-columns:repeat(7, 1fr);"  and it was rendering 8 elements. 1 ghost place holder for my-result and the 7 column headers.  The work around for this was to simply hide it by putting  <my-result style="display:none"> in your tag. The css grid system worked like a charm after that.

Comment: This solution works even in a more complex case, where `my-result` needs to be able to create new `my-result` siblings. So, imagine you have a hierarchy of `my-result` where each row can have "children" rows. In that case, using an attribute selector wouldn't work, as the first selector goes in the `tbody`, but the second can't go in an internal `tbody` nor in a `tr`.

Comment: When I use this how can I avoid getting ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError?

Comment: @gyozokudor maybe using a setTimeout

Comment: Could anybody please provide an example of this?

Comment: This seems to create the element next to an empty element with the selector's name.

Comment: If you need to delete component tags completely, you can do it manually in the parent **ngAfterViewInit**: `document.querySelectorAll('<your-component>').forEach(el => el.parentNode.removeChild(el));`

Comment: If anyone has errors with this.viewContainerRef, move code from ngOnInit to ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: Thanks! This is the only approach that worked for me. In addition to your code, I also do `this.viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement.remove()` at the end, to remove the original (empty) component.

Comment: Thanks, it also works for me. 
I needed this because NgBootstrap created automatically `<div class="modal-content">` and Angular inserted the wrapping tag `<my-component-selector>` right after, where I only wanted the component **contents** directly inside the .modal-content div. 
Also thanks for the `nativeElement.remove()` tip, it's cleaner ! Basically we recreated the inside of the component.

Comment: Is it possible to use `createEmbeddedView` with projected content instead of a `ng-template`? The idea was to be able to re-create/re-render the originally projected content when needed.

Comment: I tried this and it still renders the containing element.  [Here's a Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-jvbrq8?file=src%2Fmain.ts).  How do we get it to work without rendering the containing element?

Answer (score 53):

you can try use the new css `display: contents`

here's my toolbar scss:

```
:host {
  display: contents;
}

:host-context(.is-mobile) .toolbar {
  position: fixed;
  /* Make sure the toolbar will stay on top of the content as it scrolls past. */
  z-index: 2;
}

h1.app-name {
  margin-left: 8px;
}
```

and the html:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" class="toolbar">
  <button mat-icon-button (click)="toggle.emit()">
    <mat-icon>menu</mat-icon>
  </button>
  <img src="/assets/icons/favicon.png">
  <h1 class="app-name">@robertking Dashboard</h1>
</mat-toolbar>
```

and in use:

```
<navigation-toolbar (toggle)="snav.toggle()"></navigation-toolbar>
```

Comment: *display: contents* does the job. This is what I was looking for, it allows the child component to take its style without being hacked by extra child component's name tag(selector)

Comment: doesn't answer the original question: "render a component without its wrapping tag"

Comment: I think it's worth noting, that using `display: contents` may cause some accessibility issues, so it should rather be used with caution (at least until it's totally safe in all major browsers): https://caniuse.com/css-display-contents

Answer (score 24):

Attribute selectors are the best way to solve this issue.

So in your case:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Time</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody my-results>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

my-results ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-results, [my-results]',
  templateUrl: './my-results.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-results.component.css']
})
export class MyResultsComponent implements OnInit {

  entries: Array<any> = [
    { name: 'Entry One', time: '10:00'},
    { name: 'Entry Two', time: '10:05 '},
    { name: 'Entry Three', time: '10:10'},
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

my-results html

```
  <tr my-result [entry]="entry" *ngFor="let entry of entries"><tr>
```

my-result ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: '[my-result]',
  templateUrl: './my-result.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./my-result.component.css']
})
export class MyResultComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() entry: any;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

my-result html

```
  <td>{{ entry.name }}</td>
  <td>{{ entry.time }}</td>
```

See working stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xbbegx

Comment: selector: 'my-results, [my-results]', then I can use my-results as an attribute of the tag in HTML. 
This is the correct answer. It works in Angular 8.2.

Answer (score 14):

Use this directive on your element

```
@Directive({
   selector: '[remove-wrapper]'
})
export class RemoveWrapperDirective {
   constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
       const parentElement = el.nativeElement.parentElement;
       const element = el.nativeElement;
       parentElement.removeChild(element);
       parentElement.parentNode.insertBefore(element, parentElement.nextSibling);
       parentElement.parentNode.removeChild(parentElement);
   }
}
```

Example usage:

```
<div class="card" remove-wrapper>
   This is my card component
</div>
```

and in the parent html you call card element as usual, for example:

```
<div class="cards-container">
   <card></card>
</div>
```

The output will be:

```
<div class="cards-container">
   <div class="card" remove-wrapper>
      This is my card component
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is throwing an error because 'parentElement.parentNode' is null

Comment: Won't this mess with Angular's change detection and virtual DOM?

Comment: @BenWinding it **won't**  because Angular internally represents a component using a data structure commonly referred to as a **View** or a **Component View** and all change detection operations, including **ViewChildren** run on a View, not the DOM.
I have tested this code and I can confirm that all DOM listeners and angular bindings are working.

Comment: this solution doesn't work, throws null and destroys the ng structure

Comment: This removes the component altogether

Answer (score 8):

Another option nowadays is the `ContribNgHostModule` made available from the [`@angular-contrib/common` package](https://github.com/trotyl/angular-contrib).

After importing the module you can add `host: { ngNoHost: '' }` to your `@Component` decorator and no wrapping element will be rendered.

Comment: Just commenting because it looks like this package is not maintained anymore and there are errors with Angular 9+

Answer (score 3):

Improvement on [@Shlomi Aharoni](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1929420/shlomi-aharoni) answer. It is generally good practice to use [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) to manipulate the DOM to keep Angular in the loop and because for other reasons including security (e.g. XSS Attacks) and server-side rendering.

###### Directive example

```js
import { AfterViewInit, Directive, ElementRef, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[remove-wrapper]'
})
export class RemoveWrapperDirective implements AfterViewInit {
  
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef, private renderer: Renderer2) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    // access the DOM. get the element to unwrap
    const el = this.elRef.nativeElement;
    const parent = this.renderer.parentNode(this.elRef.nativeElement);

    // move all children out of the element
    while (el.firstChild) { // this line doesn't work with server-rendering
      this.renderer.appendChild(parent, el.firstChild);
    }

    // remove the empty element from parent
    this.renderer.removeChild(parent, el);
  }
}
```

###### Component example

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-page',
  templateUrl: './page.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./page.component.scss'],
})
export class PageComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(
    private renderer: Renderer2,
    private elRef: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {

    // access the DOM. get the element to unwrap
    const el = this.elRef.nativeElement; // app-page
    const parent = this.renderer.parentNode(this.elRef.nativeElement); // parent

    // move children to parent (everything is moved including comments which angular depends on)
    while (el.firstChild){ // this line doesn't work with server-rendering
      this.renderer.appendChild(parent, el.firstChild);
    }
    
    // remove empty element from parent - true to signal that this removed element is a host element
    this.renderer.removeChild(parent, el, true);
  }
}
```

Comment: for some reason this solution did not work for me

Answer (score 2):

This works for me and it can avoid ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError error.

**child-component**:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'child-component'
    templateUrl: './child.template.html'
})

export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
@ViewChild('childTemplate', {static: true}) childTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;

constructor(
      private view: ViewContainerRef
) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.view.createEmbeddedView(this.currentUserTemplate);
}

}
```

**parent-component**:

```
<child-component></child-component>
```

Comment: can you give answer of my question? https://stackoverflow.com/q/76146903/14344959