# Split `list` and `item` of the Angular Material grid list component in separate components?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using the Angular2 Material [grid list component](https://material.angular.io/components/component/grid-list) and I want to split the `list` and the `item` in separate components.

Here's my `list`:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  template: `
    <md-grid-list cols="12">
        <app-item *ngFor="let item of items"></app-item>
    </md-grid-list>
  `
})
export class ListComponent {
  items: Array<number> = [1, 2]; // dummy data
}
```

Here is my `item` component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  template: `
    <md-grid-tile [colspan]="6">
      First
    </md-grid-tile>
    <md-grid-tile [colspan]="6">
      Second
    </md-grid-tile>
  `
})
export class ItemComponent implements OnInit { }
```

The issue is that the child `item` component gets rendered in the actual DOM inside a wrapper `<app-item>` custom (invalid) DOM element. And the styles are broken because the Angular2 Material [grid list component](https://material.angular.io/components/component/grid-list) expects the following structure:

```
<md-grid-list cols="12">
  <!-- Item 1 -->
  <md-grid-tile [colspan]="6"></md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile [colspan]="6"></md-grid-tile>

  <!-- Item 2 -->
  <md-grid-tile [colspan]="6"></md-grid-tile>
  <md-grid-tile [colspan]="6"></md-grid-tile>
</md-grid-list>
```

... but the actual DOM structure is:

```
<md-grid-list cols="12">
  <!-- Item 1 -->
  <app-item> <!-- same issue if I replace this with `div` or `span` -->
    <md-grid-tile [colspan]="6"></md-grid-tile>
    <md-grid-tile [colspan]="6"></md-grid-tile>
  </app-item>

  <!-- Item 2 -->
  <app-item>
    <md-grid-tile [colspan]="6"></md-grid-tile>
    <md-grid-tile [colspan]="6"></md-grid-tile>
  </app-item>
</md-grid-list>
```

I have looked at `ng-content`, `DynamicComponentLoader`, the `ViewContainerRef`, but they don't seem to provide a solution to this as far as I can see.

I read the [response here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38716164/1333836), but the attribute selectors don't work for me as well. It doesn't matter if the wrapping component is `<app-item>` or `<div>` or `<span>` or whatever, the styling always breaks.

Does anybody know if I can render a child component without any parent wrapper? Is there a workaround you can suggest for my use-case?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@sergeras, [the solution you proposed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42368517/1333836) doesn't work.

I was very surprised that the approach by using attribute selectors and `<ng-container>` is causing an error and I [raised an issue](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3670) in the Angular Material 2 official repository.

Jeremy Elbourn, one of the top contributors to the Angular Material 2, provided [an explanation](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/3670#issuecomment-288250493):

> ... you can view the grid-list as a **single UI component** with a specific API. Placing the grid tiles inside of another component hides them completely from the grid list since each component is effectively a black box.

Therefore, the answer to my question is: **It is currently not possible** to separate in different Angular 2 components the list and the list item of the Angular2 Material [grid list component](https://material.angular.io/components/component/grid-list). And there is no workaround.

Comment: Thanks. I just ran into exactly the same issue. The explanation makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute selectors and `ng-container`, which would make your parent component like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-list',
  template: `
    <md-grid-list cols="12">
        <ng-container appItem *ngFor="let item of items"></ng-container>
    </md-grid-list>
  `
})
```

And then the child component would be like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[appItem]',
  template: `
    <md-grid-tile [colspan]="6">
      First
    </md-grid-tile>
    <md-grid-tile [colspan]="6">
      Second
    </md-grid-tile>
  `
})
export class VehiclesItemComponent implements OnInit { }
```

Comment: Hm, this solution fires the following error: `Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method.` Am I missing something?

Comment: I got the same result as @KaloyanKosev when I tried this. It looks like ng-container doesn't like attribute selectors...

Comment: @JoãoMendes I found [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42958860/1333836) to our question! Sadly, it turned out that the thing we want to achieve is not possible. I haven't found any workaround yet.

Comment: It does not work for grid list, but it does work in general case (outside of material2), right?