# Remove component tag in angular 6

Tags: angular

Im trying to remove the called component tag from html to prevent a some broken css from external libraries (for example, calling a sidenav from clarity project):

**something.component.ts**

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-something',
  templateUrl: './something.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./something.component.css']
})
export class SomethingComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() config: {} = {};
  ....
}
```

**something.component.html**

```
<div>
    Hello World
</div>
```

**another.component.html**

```
 <div>
    <app-something [config]="somethingConfig"></app-something>
 </div>
```

Then outputs:

```
 <div>
    <app-something>
      <div>
          Hello World
      </div>
    </app-something>
</div>
```

And I want:

```
<div>
  <div>
     Hello World
  </div>
</div>
```

Yes, i know, many answers about it in stackoverflow and basically i can resume all the answers in 2 items :

- **Add brackets to selector** (`selector: '[app-something]'`): Doesnt works, it triggers an error

  > The selector of the component SomethingComponent should be used as element (https://angular.io/styleguide#style-05-03)
  >   (component-selector).
- **Use a Directive**: Directives cannot have `templateUrl` param.

Comment: Using the attribute selector seems to be the best way of solving this problem. The error you are getting is not due to angular not supporting the square brackets to achieve this, something else must be going wrong in your application. I suggest looking into examples on how to use the attribute selector for components.

Comment: Also remember to change ```<div>
  <div>
     Hello World
  </div>
</div>```

to `
<div>
  <div app-something></div>
</div>`

Comment: @enf0rcer you right. Isnt a angular problem, its a tslint.json configuration. Put your answer to select as right answer. Thanks man.

Comment: Awesome man, glad you found it! I added the answer.

Comment: similar: https://stackoverflow.com/q/46671235/606662

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using the attribute selector seems to be the best way of solving this problem. The error you are getting is not due to angular not supporting the square brackets to achieve this, something else must be going wrong in your application. I suggest looking into examples on how to use the attribute selector for components.

Also remember to change

```
<div> 
    <div>Hello World</div>
</div>
```

to

```
<div> 
    <div app-something></div> 
</div>
```

for the attribute selector to be effective.

Comment: What if the component accepts some input how do we pass it to the component?

Comment: It's the same as usual: `<div app-something [inputName]="inputVar"></div>`

Comment: What if I want to render 3 TD elements with a single Component? _attribute selector_ does not work here.

Comment: @Alex75 as far as I know that should work as well. Though I havent used angular in a long time.

Answer (score 4):

From your component, change selector to `div[app-something]`

```js
import {Component, OnInit, Input} from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'div[app-something]',
  templateUrl: './something.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./something.component.css']
})
export class SomethingComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() config: {} = {};
  ....
}
```

Then you can use that component together with `div` tag

```
<div> 
    <div app-something [config]="config"></div> 
</div>
```