# Angular - unwrap Component template

Tags: angular

Edit: interesting discussion on [GitHub - Angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7857)

Currently I have a `@Component`'s template such as

```html
selector: 'app-input',
template: `
  <nz-form-item>
    <nz-form-control [nzSm]="14" [nzXs]="24">
      <input [formControl]="formControl">
    </nz-form-control>
  </nz-form-item>
`,
```

This `@Component` is then used as

```html
<form nz-form [formGroup]="formGroup">
  <app-input [formControlName]="name"></app-input>
  <app-input [formControlName]="code"></app-input>
  ...
```

However, the NG-ZORRO styles are correctly applied only when the `nz-form-item` is directly nested under `nz-form`

```html
<form nz-form ...
  <nz-form-item ...
```

As of now, instead, the layout is

```html
<form nz-form ...
  <app-input ...
    <nz-form-item ...
```

Is there a way to *un-wrap* the `app-input` template?
Or, is there an alternative approach to go for?

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716105/angular2-render-a-component-without-its-wrapping-tag

Comment: @taras-d thanks! This seems an updated version https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671235/remove-host-component-tag-from-html-in-angular-4

Comment: @taras-d however, I'd have to keep the `nz-form-item` external to the `app-input` component