# Cannot use mat-tab in an attribute selector

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-directive

I try to put the two tabs into two separate components like the following:

```
<mat-tab-group animationDuration="0ms">
    <mat-tab app-tab [label]="'blabla1'" [data]="aaaData"></mat-tab>
    <mat-tab app-tab [label]="'blabla2'" [data]="bbbData"></mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

...

```
@Component({
    selector: 'mat-tab[app-tab]',
    templateUrl: './tab.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tab.component.scss']
})
export class TabComponent {
    @Input() label: string;
    @Input() data: any;
```

and in module.ts:

```
import {MatTabsModule} from '@angular/material';
@NgModule({
    imports: [
        MatTabsModule,
```

And I get the error:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   More than one component matched on this element.
>   Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element.
>   Conflicting components: MatTab,TabComponent ("

Or, if I use `a mat-tab-link` instead of `mat-tab`, and `a[mat-tab-link][app-tab]` instead of `mat-tab[app-tab]`, I will get the

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'data' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("mat-tab-group animationDuration="0ms">

and it doesn't support the `label` property either:

> Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
>   Can't bind to 'label' since it isn't a known property of 'a'. ("s="tabs-wrap">][label]="'blabla1'" [data]="aaaData">

Comment: Have you tried to change your selector to `selector: '[app-tab]'`?

Comment: After reading your question again, I think it's not possible at all. `mat-tab` selector is already associated with another component and the two definitions (material's and yours) will conflict. The best you can do is create another component and put inside `mat-tab`. Maybe you can work with `ng-template`'s in some way.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors: More than one component matched on this element. Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element. Conflicting components: MatTab,TabComponent ("
```

because you are declaring a mat-tab selector compoment in your project which cannot be done becaouse the same name component is already present.

You can rename the selector of component in the tab component from

`mat-tab[app-tab]` to  `app-tab`

then you can use it in the mat-tab like this

```html
<mat-tab>
   <app-tab [label]="'blabla2'" [data]="bbbData"></app-tab>
</mat-tab>
```

The error are because the label and data are not the attributes of the mat-tab.

Use your component separately in the mat tab component

Comment: Then why does this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46671235/remove-host-component-tag-from-html-in-angular-4 work?

Comment: here the tr tag is the default browser tag and not the component. Here the mat-tab is defined component in angular material which you cannot define it again.

Answer (score 0):

I would place another element within the `mat-tab` to avoid messing with Material's component selectors.

So more like:

```
<mat-tab-group animationDuration="0ms">
    <mat-tab label="blabla1">
        <tab-component [data]="aaaData"></tab-component>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="blabla2">
        <tab-component [data]="bbbData"></tab-component>
    </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

```
@Component({
    selector: 'tab-component',
    templateUrl: './tab.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./tab.component.scss']
})
export class TabComponent {
    @Input() data: any;
```