# Strip off parent component tag

Tags: angular, angular-components

I have declared a `<table>` element in a HTML-template and put a `custom-component`  in it's row, like this:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    ....
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <CustomComponent></CustomComponent>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

`CustomComponent` contains some `<td>`s.
i want to strip `<CustomComponent></CustomComponent>` off, So that internal `<td>`s be the first children of `<tr>`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 : render a component without its wrapping tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716105/angular2-render-a-component-without-its-wrapping-tag)

Comment: @rainmak3r Yes. exactly what i want.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and tested the below, hope it should work.

```
   // select element to unwrap
    var el = document.getElementsByTagName("CustomComponent");

    // get the element's parent node, if it returns array then take the first index
    var parent = el[0].parentNode;

    // move all children out of the element
    while (el[0].firstChild) {
        parent.insertBefore(el[0].firstChild, el[0]);
    }

    // remove the empty element
    parent.removeChild(el[0]);
```

Happy Coding!