# Create repeatable Angular component with two rows for tables

Tags: html, angular, components

I have two components. The first one represents a table of items and the second one represents one item. The first one is repeating the second one many times.

***The List Component (`app-list`):***

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item" app-item></tr>    
</table>
```

***The Item Component (`app-item`):***

```
<td>
    <img src="https://someimage.com/{{item.img}}.jpg">
</td>
<td>
    <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
</td>
<td>
    {{item.description}}
</td>
```

In order for this to work, I had to use an attribute selector for the `app-item` component:

```
@Component({
  selector: '[app-item]'
})
```

This works perfectly.

---

Now I want to improve it and add a second row in each `app-item`. My problem is that the `tr` tag lies in the `app-list` component instead of the `app-item` component. I thought that if I move it to the `app-item` component, I could add another `tr` and be able to show two rows per one item. So this is what I did. After that I used `ng-container` to repeat the items in my `app-list`, in order to avoid adding a wrapper tag around my two rows:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item" app-item></ng-container>
```

This solution did not work. I got the following error:

```
ERROR TypeError: el.setAttribute is not a function
    at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DefaultDomRenderer2.setAttribute (platform-browser.js:1089)
    at EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.EmulatedEncapsulationDomRenderer2.applyToHost (platform-browser.js:1157)
    at DomRendererFactory2.push../node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/fesm5/platform-browser.js.DomRendererFactory2.createRenderer (platform-browser.js:1015)
```

**Can you help me resolve this error or suggest another implementation?**

---

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

The better version @Serhiy is suggesting

***The table:***

```
<table>
  <app-item *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item" remove-component-tag></app-item>
</table>
```

***The directive:***

```
import { Directive, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[remove-component-tag]'
})
export class RemoveComponentTagDirective {
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {

    let element = el.nativeElement;
    let children = el.nativeElement.childNodes;

    setTimeout(()=>{
      let reversedChildren = [];
      children.forEach(child => {
        reversedChildren.unshift(child);
      });
      reversedChildren.forEach(child => {
        element.parentNode.insertBefore(child, element.nextSibling);
      });
      element.remove(element);
    }, 0);

  }
}
```

The timeout is necessary for some reason and works even with 0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't see the right "angular" way to do it, but you should be able to use directives to clear your html during render.

Saw this approach in comments here: [Angular2 : render a component without its wrapping tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716105/angular2-render-a-component-without-its-wrapping-tag)

I tried that and it worked for me:

Parent component:

```
<table>

  <div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <app-item [item]="item" remove-wrapper></app-item>  
  </div>

</table>
```

Child component:

```
<tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://someimage.com/{{item.img}}.jpg">
    </td>

    <td>
      <h3>{{item.name}}</h3>
    </td>

    <td>
      {{item.description}}
    </td>      

</tr>

<tr>
    <td>
      <img src="https://someimage.com/{{item.img}}.jpg">
    </td>

    <td>
      <h3>{{item.name + ' 2'}}</h3>
    </td>

    <td>
      {{item.description + ' 2'}}
    </td>      

</tr>
```

Directive:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[remove-wrapper]'
})

export class RemoveWrapperDirective {

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {

    let parent = el.nativeElement.parentElement;
    let children = el.nativeElement.childNodes;

    setTimeout(()=>{
      parent.parentNode.insertBefore(children[1], parent.nextSibling);
      parent.parentNode.insertBefore(children[0], parent.nextSibling);
      parent.remove(parent);
    }, 10);

  }
}
```

Without a timeout, it crashed for me. The code can be improved, but you can start from here.

Comment: It is a little hacky, but it should work. I am wondering if there is another "more proper" way to do it

Answer (score 2):

thank you for that solution.
I want to add a correction for your code to avoid the usage of the `setTimeout` function.
Implementing the `OnInit` interface for the directive and move the code from the constructor to the `ngOnInit` method will keep the code clean.

```
import { Directive, OnInit, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[remove-component-tag]'
})
export class RemoveComponentTagDirective implements OnInit{

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    let element = this.el.nativeElement;
    let children = this.el.nativeElement.childNodes;

    let reversedChildren = [];
    children.forEach(child => {
      reversedChildren.unshift(child);
    });
    reversedChildren.forEach(child => {
      element.parentNode.insertBefore(child, element.nextSibling);
    });
    element.remove(element);
  }
}
```

Take a look at [Angular lifecycle hooks](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks)

Answer (score 0):

Would using component syntax instead of directive syntax help here?

Instead of:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item" app-item></ng-container>
```

Try:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
    <app-item [item]="item"></app-item>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I have already tried this. The app-item tag is shown in the final HTML around the tr tags and this ruins the table. My goal is to get rid of all other tags except the trs

Answer (score 0):

An alternative is to apply

```
:host { display: table-row-group; }
```

to the app-item component, this makes it behave like a `tbody` and the inner rows will behave as expected.