# Why is input not working for my angular component?

Tags: angular

I have an angular class:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'main-title',
  styleUrls: ['main_title.scss'],
  template: `
      <ng-template>
          <div class="main-title">
              <h2 [ngClass]="{'-small': isSmall }"
                  class="{{titleClassName}}" data-cy="main-title">{{title}}</h2>
          </div>
      </ng-template>
  `,
})
export class MainTitle extends NoRootTagComponent {

  /**
   * Accepts strings or array (will map to multiple lines)
   */
  @Input('title')
  title: string

  @Input('titleClassName')
  titleClassName = ''

  @Input()
  isSmall?: boolean

  constructor(vcRef: ViewContainerRef, public router: AsyncRouter) {
    super(vcRef)
  }
}
```

and using it like this:

```
<main-title
  [isSmall]="true"
  titleClassName="h5"
  title="please verify your zip code."></main-title>
```

However I don't see the boolean is `isSmall` being passed. It remains `undefined` for some reason. Is it because of the `NoRootTagComponent`? I can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: How do you know that `isSmall` remains `undefined`?

Comment: I didn't show it here, but I used `console.log(this.isSmall)` in `ngOnInit` and it shows undefined.

Comment: can you try omitting the question mark from the `isSmall` variable name ?

Comment: @Spacebear5000, if you don't want a tag, you can use attributte selector https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716105/angular2-render-a-component-without-its-wrapping-tag. I supouse your problem is how is implemented NoRootTagComponent. you need pass a "context" to view, or get the reference of the Embebd component and give the value

Answer (score 0):

Wherever you insert the ng-template will be place where the `isSmall` is checked, so that is why its giving `undefined`, you need not pass `isSmall` to the child component instead define it in the component where the `ng-template` is inserted!

Comment: So you mean in the parent component?

Comment: @Spacebear5000 Yes, but in your case, you will need to set the context, check this example for [reference](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-template-outlet)

Comment: @Spacebear5000 If you're going for `ng-template` inside the a component, then it does not serve a purpose since the child component will not render anything right?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean. `titleClassName` and `title` work as it. Why wouldn't `isSmall` work in this case?

Comment: @Spacebear5000 can you provide a working stackblitz with the issue!, the data provided isn't sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess here; the problem lies within the SCSS definition of the styles.

Are you trying to do something like this?

```css
.main-title {
    color: blue;

    &-small {
        font-size: 8px;
    }
}
```

Because your component is going to render as `<h2 class="some-class -small">` (Notice the space) and a style rule like the one above is not going to be applied.

Instead I'd suggest something like this for your component's template:

```html
  <div class="main-title">
    <h2 class="{{ isSmall? titleClassName+'-small' : titleClassName }}" data-cy="main-title">
      {{title}}
    </h2>
  </div>
```

Also, notice I removed the `<ng-template>` tag. You don't need it for this component. Hope this helped you.