# Using dynamic component within Angular structural directive produces extra HTML tag. How to remove or replace it?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-directive, angular2-directives, angular-dynamic-components

I have quite complex infrastructure in my project which contains of

- host component
- structural directive used in host component's template (MyDir)
- another component used in structural directive (MyComp)

Simplified version looks like the following.

**host component**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
<table>
  <tr *myDir="let item of data">
    <td>{{item.text}}</td>
  </tr>
</table>`
})
export class AppComponent  {
  data = [ { text: 'item 1' }, { text: 'item 2' } ];
}
```

**structural directive**

```
import { MyComp } from './myComp';

@Directive({ selector: '[myDir][myDirOf]' })
export class MyDir implements OnInit {
  private data: any;

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {
  }

  @Input() set myDirOf(data: any) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const templateView = this.templateRef.createEmbeddedView({});
    const compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComp);
    const componentRef = this.viewContainer.createComponent(
      compFactory, undefined, this.viewContainer.injector, [templateView.rootNodes]
    );
    componentRef.instance.data = this.data;
    componentRef.instance.template = this.templateRef;
  }
}
```

**structural directive's component**

```
@Component({
  selector: '[my-comp]',
  template: `
<tr><td>custom td</td></tr>
<ng-template *ngFor="let item of data"
  [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"
  [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: item }"
></ng-template>`
})
export class MyComp {
  public template: TemplateRef<any>;
  public data: any;
}
```

The output is

> custom td 
>   item 1 
>   item 2

which is fine except the markup which is

```html
<table>
  <div my-comp>
    <tr><td>custom td</td></tr>
    <tr><td>item 1</td></tr>
    <tr><td>item 2</td></tr>
  </div>
</table>
```

**Problem**

I want to remove intermediate `<div my-comp>` from the result view or at least replace it with `<tbody>`. To see the whole picture I prepared [Stackblitz DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-structural-dir-with-comp-table), hope it will help... Also, it might be obvious the example is artificial, but this is what I came with trying to reproduce the issue with minimal code. So the problem should have a solution in the given infrastructure.

**Update**

@AlexG found simple way to replace intermediate `div` with `tbody` and stackblitz demo showed a good result at first. But when I tried to apply it to my project locally I faced new issue: browser arranges its own `tbody` before the dynamic contents of the table are ready to render, which results in two nested `tbody` in the end view, which seems inconsistent per html specs

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
      <tbody my-comp>
        <tr><td>custom td</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item 1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>item 2</td></tr>
    </tbody>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Stackblitz demo has no such problem, only `tbody my-comp` is present. But exactly the same project in my local dev environment does. So I'm  still trying to find a way how to **remove** intermediate `my-comp` container.

**Update 2**

The [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-structural-dir-with-comp-table) had been updated in accordance with the solution suggested by @markdBC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My answer is inspired by Slim's answer to a similar question found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56887630/12962012.

You can remove the intermediate `<div my-comp>` by

1. Creating a `TemplateRef` object representing the template of the `MyComp` component inside the `MyComp` component.
2. Accessing this `TemplateRef` object from the structural directive.
3. Creating an embedded view inside the view container with the `TemplateRef` object from the structural directive.

The resulting code looks something like:

**`MyComp` component**

```
@Component({
  selector: "[my-comp]",
  template: `
    <ng-template #mytemplate>
      <tr>
        <td>custom td</td>
      </tr>
      <ng-template
        *ngFor="let item of data"
        [ngTemplateOutlet]="template"
        [ngTemplateOutletContext]="{ $implicit: item }"
      ></ng-template>
    </ng-template>
  `
})
export class MyComp {
  public template: TemplateRef<any>;
  public data: any;
  @ViewChild("mytemplate", { static: true }) mytemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
}
```

**`MyDir` directive**

```
export class MyDir implements OnInit {
  private version: string;
  private data: any;

  constructor(
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef,
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
  ) {}

  @Input() set myDirOf(data: any) {
    this.data = data;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const compFactory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(MyComp);
    const componentRef = compFactory.create(this.viewContainer.injector);
    componentRef.instance.data = this.data;
    componentRef.instance.template = this.templateRef;
    this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(componentRef.instance.mytemplate);
  }
}
```

The resulting HTML looks something like:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>custom td</td></tr>
  <tr><td>item 1</td></tr>
  <tr><td>item 2</td></tr>
</table>
```

I've prepared a StackBlitz demo at https://stackblitz.com/edit/table-no-div-wrapper.

Comment: Looks like it's your first answer on SO and it is so helpful! Please continue to contribute,  the community needs you!

Answer (score 2):

Change the selector of your component from `[my-comp]` to `tbody [my-comp]` and your will have a `<tbody my-comp>` instead of a `<div my-comp>` which would be sufficient if I understood you correctly.

Comment: I updated the Question... seems we have a problem with `tbody`, browser is too smart and your approach causes nested `tbody` appearance in real environment