# Using mat-accordion and mat-expansion-panel in ngFor

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to loop some items with an ngFor and create a mat-expansion-panel for each item.

I would like to encapsulate the logic for each item into an item component:

```
    <item></item>
```

Initial attempt:

```
<mat-accordion>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items" >
    <item [item]="item"></item>
  </div>
</mat-accordion>
```

Where item template is:

```
    <mat-expansion-panel>
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        Header Content
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>

      <div>
         Expandable content
      </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
```

The problem with this approach is that there is an extra html element for my component between `<mat-accordion>` and `<mat-expansion-panel>`, which messes up the css for the accordion.

Is there a way that my component can provide the header and content?

```
    <mat-accordion>
      <div *ngFor="let item of items" >
          <mat-expansion-panel>
            <mat-expansion-panel-header>
              <!-- put item component header here->
            </mat-expansion-panel-header>

          <div>
            <!-- put item component content here->
          </div>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
      </div>
    </mat-accordion>
```

I have read up on ng-content, but I think that is backwards from what I want, I don't want to shove custom content into my component, I want to extract elements from my component and have them render in the parent.

I do realize I could create 2 components, item-header and item-content.  However I would really like to keep that login in one component.

Comment: are you trying to create a generic component?

Comment: @Aravind I suppose not generic in the sense that each item will always be an expansion panel.  Which relates to my first attempt.  However that create an extra element that screws with the material css.

Comment: Would putting the *ngFor on the <mat-accordion not solve the extra element issue?

Comment: @JMP wouldn't that create an accordion for each item?

Comment: Shouldn’t do. Should repeat what is within the tag, e.g. <ul> with for repeats the <li> within. But haven’t tried on mat-accordian and been long day so could be wrong!

Comment: What CSS is getting messed up by having the additional element in there?

Comment: @KurtHamilton material angular expects the accordion to have mat-expansion-panel as direct children.  I can look at the css, but imagine this is a common problem.

Comment: @JMP ngFor on accordion creates multiple accordion elements, this is not correct, there should only be one.

Comment: Take  <mat-expansion-panel> out of the template and loop on that? Last guess!

Comment: @JMP nope, tried that as well :(  Angular material throws an error if there is not a <mat-expansion-panel-header> as a direct child of <mat-expansion-panel>.  Looping on the panel creates the component element between those 2.  In angularJS I would use replace: true on the directive, however that was deprecated and not ported to angular.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 : render a component without its wrapping tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716105/angular2-render-a-component-without-its-wrapping-tag)

Comment: Can you please create basic stackblitz instance where we can see the issue ?

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same problem. A [Pull Request is opened](https://github.com/angular/components/pull/13497) on this subject but never merged. 
We can improve a little the layout (border radius), by adding this code below. To keep things simple, best we can do is to restore `border-radius` on top and bottom of first and last panel.

But it's more difficult for bottom of previous panel not expanded, and top of next panel not expanded...

main component.html :

```html
<mat-accordion class="custom-accordion">
  <item *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"></item>
</mat-accordion>
```

item.component.ts:

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-item',
  template: `
    <mat-expansion-panel>
      <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        Header Content
      </mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <div>
        Expandable content
      </div>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
  `,
  host: {
    'class': 'expansion-panel-wrapper',
    '[class.expanded]': 'expansionPanel && expansionPanel.expanded',
  }
})
export class ItemComponent {
  @ViewChild(MatExpansionPanel, { static: false }) expansionPanel;
  ...
}
```

in styles.scss :

```
.custom-accordion.mat-accordion {
  .expansion-panel-wrapper:first-of-type .mat-expansion-panel {
    border-top-right-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
  }

  & > :not(.expanded) .mat-expansion-panel {
    border-radius: 0;
  }

  & > .expansion-panel-wrapper:last-of-type > .mat-expansion-panel {
    border-bottom-right-radius: 4px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 4px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice catch - I totally missed the very slight errors in styling in my answer. Upvoted as a much better answer.

Comment: Don't think they will merge that PR.  More info here as well: https://github.com/angular/components/issues/6870#issuecomment-327847741.  Mentions tight coupling discussion between accordion and expansion panel.  Guess its either hack the css, or make 2 components, one for header and one for content.

Comment: I have changed css a bit, changed part:
`& > .expansion-panel-wrapper:first-of-type > .mat-expansion-panel {border-top-right-radius: 4px; border-top-left-radius: 4px;} & > .expansion-panel-wrapper > .mat-expansion-panel:not(.mat-expanded) { border-radius: 0;}`
Now we don't need to use `@ViewChild` and `host.class-expanded`

Answer (score 5):

You were almost there. You don't need to have any wrapping element - you can simply use *ngFor directly on your component:

```
<mat-accordion>
    <item *ngFor="let item of items" [item]="item"></item>
</mat-accordion>
```

Working stack-blitz with simple example of working code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pvse7t

Comment: Yup, think you caught it below, css is not correct with the extra component element.

Answer (score -1):

By looking at the code, I think your problem comes from this:

```
<mat-accordion>
  <div *ngFor="let item of items" > **//this right here creates a 'div' element for each loop**
    <item [item]="item"></item>
  </div>
</mat-accordion>
```

Try replacing the div with ng-container instead:

```
<mat-accordion>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items" > **//ng-container is never rendered in the DOM**
    <item [item]="item"></item>
  </ng-container>
</mat-accordion>
```

Answer (score -2):

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/38716164/11928194 , try

```
<mat-accordion>
  <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items" >
    <mat-expansion-panel item  [item]="item"></mat-expansion-panel>
  </ng-container>
</mat-accordion>
```

With ItemComponent selector as '[item]'

Comment: Pretty sure you cannot apply an attribute selector on another component. Error "More than one component matched on this element.
Make sure that only one component's selector can match a given element."

Comment: My bad. Shouldn't have posted untested answers.

Answer (score -2):

Why not apply `ngFor` to the expansion panel directly?

```html
<mat-accordion>
  <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let item of items">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
      <mat-panel-title>
        Header Content
      </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <ng-template matExpansionPanelContent>
      Expandable Content
    </ng-template>
  </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

I was trying to share a link from Stackblitz, but unfortunately it seems we have a bug there with sharing, so I'm going to share a screenshot of what I mean:

[image]

Edit: it seems Stackblitz decided to cooperate now. Here is the link: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ae7cfr

Comment: Check the question again, along with other comments.  The problem is this messes up the css styling for the panels due to the extra html element.

Comment: @lostintranslation, I would like you to reconsider in case one of the downvotes came from you, even if this answer didn't help you. The reason is that my answer doesn't actually introduce a new element and is in reality different from the other answers. In your question, you ngFor a wrapping div. Sidson Aidson and Kaustubh Badrike ngFor a wrapping ng-container. TotallyNewb ngFor the component that has the expansion panel (essentially the same as ngFor a wrapping ng-container). Mine ngFor the expansion panel directly and you could use this as a component that has the list as an input.