# How to load components dynamically without their Host Wrapper Tag

Tags: angular, angularjs, angularjs-directive, components, viewchild

I'm loading component template during Drop Event using `"createComponent()" method of ViewContainerRef class`. all works okay but it loads component with it's Host Wrapper (selector) tag. but I want to load component dynamically without its Host wrapper tag.

here is [**my stackblitz url. You can Test This on stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-version-hhnrtf?devToolsHeight=33&file=src%2Fapp%2FpageBuild%2Fdirectives%2Fdynamic-component-loader.directive.ts)

We can load component using `"createEmbeddedView"` method of ViewContainerRef class.

> page-container.component.html

```
<div class="page-container" appDropable [element]="element">
    <ng-template *ngFor="let elemData of elementData?.content; let i = index" [type]="elemData.type" appDynamicComponent>
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

> dynamic-component.directive.ts

```
import { ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, Directive, Input, OnInit, Type, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ContainerComponent } from 'src/app/components/elements/simple-container/container.component';
import { LabelComponent } from 'src/app/components/elements/label/label.component';

export type ElementType = 'LabelComponent' | 'ContainerComponent';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDynamicComponent]',
})
export class DynamicComponentDirective implements OnInit {

  elementType: ElementType | undefined;

  appComponents: { [key in ElementType]: Type<any> } = {
    'LabelComponent': LabelComponent,
    'ContainerComponent': ContainerComponent,
  };


  @Input('type')
  set elemType(type: ElementType) {
    this.elementType = type;
  }

  componentRef: undefined | ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadComponent();
  }

  loadComponent() {
    if (this.elementType) {
      const componentElemType = this.appComponents[this.elementType];
      const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentElemType);
      if (componentFactory) {
        this.componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
        //console.log("Created Component", this.elementType)
        //console.log(this.componentRef.instance)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> label.component.html

```
<ng-template #childComponentTemplate>
<label>
    This is my Label
</label>
</ng-template>
```

> label.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, TemplateRef, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-label',
  templateUrl: './label.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./label.component.scss']
})
export class LabelComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild('childComponentTemplate', { static: true }) childComponentTemplate!: TemplateRef<any>;

  constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    console.log(this.childComponentTemplate);
    this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.childComponentTemplate);
    console.log(this.viewContainerRef.element.nativeElement);

  }
}
```

**Description of Above Code :-** elementData?.content is a array object. On Drop Event I push element Type in elementData?.content array.

Now when If elementData?.content not empty than dynamicComponent creating the component based of their ElementType. but viewContainerRef's createComponent() method loading component with its Host Wrapper tag.

for e.g. if ElementType = 'LabelComponent' than loaded component display in inspect element as like below

```
<app-label><label>This is my Label</label></app-label>
```

But I want to load without its Host Tag (`<app-label></app-label>`)

that's why I deaclared ViewChild In the LabelComponent & onInit Event    `this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.childComponentTemplate);` that ng-template referance variable pass on to createEmbeddedView method

Now, declaring viewChild in Labelcomponent I achieved what I need.

---

**My Question is :- may be this is bad idea to use createEmbeddedView() after the createComponent().**. can anyone give me a better solution for load component dynamically without its host tag using Component Type.

Please Let me correct if I'm wrong about this use of createEmbeddedView() after loading that component using createComponent().

Thank You.

---

**Updated: 18th June, 2023**

If you wish to create component dynamically as a EmbeddedView(without its host tag) then you can refer below updated code...

> **IMPORTANT NOTIC:-**
> If you load component as a EmbeddedView using below way. then Note that, `@HostListener()` & `@HostBinding()` inside `WhatEverComponent.ts` file. even angular life cycle events (onInit, AfterViewInit, AfterViewCheck, OnDestroy etc all) also not works for `WhatEverComponent.ts` file.
> But `@HostListener()` & `@HostBinding()` works perfectly in "Directive Class". even angular life cycle events also works perfectly. only Angular Life Cycle Event Hooks not works for WhatEverComponent.ts file if we create emebeddedView of WhatEverComponent

> dynamic-component.directive.ts

```
import { ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, Directive, Injector, Input, OnInit, Type, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { ContainerComponent } from 'src/app/components/elements/simple-container/container.component';
import { LabelComponent } from 'src/app/components/elements/label/label.component';

export type ElementType = 'LabelComponent' | 'ContainerComponent';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appDynamicComponent]',
})
export class DynamicComponentDirective implements OnInit {

  elementType: ElementType | undefined;

  appComponents: { [key in ElementType]: Type<any> } = {
    'LabelComponent': LabelComponent,
    'ContainerComponent': ContainerComponent,
  };


  @Input('type')
  set elemType(type: ElementType) {
    this.elementType = type;
  }

  componentRef: undefined | ComponentRef<any>;

  constructor(private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, private injector: Injector) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadComponent();
  }

  loadComponent() {
    if (this.elementType) {
      const componentElemType = this.appComponents[this.elementType];
      const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(componentElemType);
      if (componentFactory) {
        this.componentRef = componentFactory.create(this.injector); // create component.
        // this.componentRef = this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory); // create component & inserts its host view into this container

        if (this.componentRef.instance.childComponentTemplate) {
          this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.componentRef.instance.childComponentTemplate);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

here is [**my stackblitz url. You can Test This on stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-version-hhnrtf?devToolsHeight=33&file=src%2Fapp%2FpageBuild%2Fdirectives%2Fdynamic-component-loader.directive.ts)

So, **My Updated QUestion** is how to create EmbeddedView Dynamically without affecting life cycle event like ngOnInit, ngAfterViewInit ?