# How to avoid Angular using extra tag for a child component?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components, ng-container

Let's say I have parent and child component in Angular 12. For example, their templates looks like this:

Parent:

```
<h1>This is parent component</h1>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">Foo</div>
        <ng-container>
            <app-child-component></app-child-component>
        </ng-container>
    </div>
</div>
```

*I must use ng-container*

Child:

```
<button>Click</button>
```

What angular does is create wrapper around child's component template, something like this:

```
    <h1>This is parent component</h1>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">Foo</div>
            <app-child-component>
                <button>Click</button>
            </app-child-component>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The desired effect I want to achieve is:

```
        <h1>This is parent component</h1>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">Foo</div>
                <button>Click</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

I tried using attribute selector, i.e.

```
<div app-child-component></div>
```

But that adds extra *div* element I do not want.
Attribute selectors can not be used on ng-template etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular2 : render a component without its wrapping tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716105/angular2-render-a-component-without-its-wrapping-tag)

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler
No. The accepted answer uses attribute selector, as I previously tried. Other answers does not work as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `<ng-content></ng-content>`
on Child component Like :

```
<div>
   <ng-content></ng-content>
</div>
```

After That You can try:

```
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">Foo</div>
        <app-child-component>
            <button>Click</button>
        </app-child-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also you can check [medium](https://medium.com/dvt-engineering/content-projection-in-angular-c23320ba3a70) For more Detalis

Comment: That solves this simplified problem. The real problem is ... recursive. Child component has nested components(of same type - Child) ...

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is something that is very difficult to overcome in angular, it always creates host element.

There is one way to flatten hierarchy but it will add redundant node.

You have to use `ng-template` in `app-child-component`:

```
<ng-template #temlate><button>Click</button></ng-template>
```

Then inject `ViewContainerRef` to `app-child-component`.

Use `ViewContainerRef` to render template:

```
// i don't remember exact usage
viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(tempalteRef, null, viewContainerRef.length);
```

It will render template below `app-child-component` node, so the result will be like this:

```
<h1>This is parent component</h1>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">Foo</div>
        <app-child-component></app-child-component>
        <button>Click</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Then you can hide `app-child-component` node:

```
:host {
   display: none;
}
```